# how can I use active Record queries with salesforce as the data-store?

Tags: rest, activerecord, salesforce

I am connecting to Salesforce.com as a data-store and accessing their REST API's.

Currently, to do a query,  have to use SOQL, which is a query language.

How can I use ActiveRecord type 'where' queries instead?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use SOQL to retrieve records via the Salesforce.com REST API, if you are retrieving by the Id of the record. To do this, you can just use the following syntax:

> /vXX.X/sobjects/SObjectName/id/

To retrieve records that meet a specific clause other than ID, I don't believe there is an alternative to SOQL at this point *directly* in the REST API.

However, if you are using Ruby, there is a Ruby Toolkit for salesforce that does support using active record style syntax. This is an open source project and you can find out more about it here:

http://quintonwall.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/RubyToolkit-gettingstarted.pdf

Here are a couple of examples from the above document:

[image: Active Record Example 1]

[image: Active Record Example 2]

There are toolkits for other languages, but I am not sure of their support for Active Record style record access.

Comment: thanks, I am using Ruby, in fact, I had checked out the site and saw lots of different types of options so wasn't clear.  That method I thought required the salesforce to be the database of record.....I'm accessing it through Oauth...?

Comment: Hi Angela - I'm not sure what you mean by "salesforce to be the database of record", perhaps you need to put more details in your question to clarify what you mean. As for OAuth, that doesn't really matter. Once you've authenticated against salesforce you can access the REST API with either your OAuth token, or your salesforce session ID.